# How to architect my jquery plugin to ensure I can activate multiple instances on same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jquery plugin which can be activated on an text input. The idea is to show a default greyed out helper text. Something very similar to what can be seen on https://squareup.com/

A first version of the plugin code is as follows:

```
(function($) {
    var settings;
    $.fn.activate = function(callerSettings) {

        settings = $.extend({
            controlID: null,
            default_value: null,
            IsActive: false
        }, callerSettings || {});

        $(settings.controlID).focus(function() {
            if (!settings.IsActive) {
                if (this.value == settings.default_value) {
                    this.value = '';
                    $(this).css('color', '#333');
                }
                settings.IsActive = true;
            }
        });

        $(settings.controlID).blur(function() {
            if (settings.IsActive) {
                if (this.value == '') {
                    $(this).css('color', '#CCC');
                    this.value = settings.default_value;
                    settings.IsActive = false;
                }
                else {
                    settings.IsActive = true;
                }
            }
        });

        Init();       

        return this;
    };

    var Init = function() {

        if (settings.IsActive) {
            $(settings.controlID).css('color', "#000");
        }
        else {        
            $(settings.controlID).css('color', "#CCC");            
            $(settings.controlID).val(settings.default_value);
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

But when I am activating multiple instances of the plugin, it is not working properly.

So could anyone please guide me how to architect this to have multiple instances? Or perhaps what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your instances are using the same `settings`.

Instead of:

```
(function($) {
    var settings;
    $.fn.activate = function(callerSettings) {

        settings = $.extend({
```

try:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.activate = function(callerSettings) {

        var settings = $.extend({
```

The problem will be with Init – how do you use it? If you only use it in $.fn.activate() then define it there or just inline it:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.activate = function(callerSettings) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            controlID: null,
            default_value: null,
            IsActive: false
        }, callerSettings || {});

        $(settings.controlID).focus(function() {
            if (!settings.IsActive) {
                if (this.value == settings.default_value) {
                    this.value = '';
                    $(this).css('color', '#333');
                }
                settings.IsActive = true;
            }
        });

        $(settings.controlID).blur(function() {
            if (settings.IsActive) {
                if (this.value == '') {
                    $(this).css('color', '#CCC');
                    this.value = settings.default_value;
                    settings.IsActive = false;
                }
                else {
                    settings.IsActive = true;
                }
            }
        });

        if (settings.IsActive) {
            $(settings.controlID).css('color', "#000");
        }
        else {        
            $(settings.controlID).css('color', "#CCC");            
            $(settings.controlID).val(settings.default_value);
        }

        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Is it better now? I didn't test it.

Comment: That's the kind of thing that will help - can you then pass `settings` to the `Init` function?

Comment: Yes. You can do one of 3 things: you can pass settings to Init(), you can define Init() in the scope of the `settings` or you can inline the function if this is the only place that you use it.

Comment: I think in this case I can keep the settings within the activate as you have shown. And remove the init from outside to within the activate. Let me try that and test it out.

Comment: Well it seems to be working fine.. however, I had kept the settings variable outside as I had read about it in the book "jquery in action". I cant really recall right now the reason they had done so. But I will read up and post here if there is anything interesting.

Comment: I just read the example again in the book. The reason they had defined settings outside was so that it is available to other functions withing the plugin. Basically, they were writing a common function instead of writing it multiple times within the activate. So the code was not getting repeated. But they had mentioned that the assumption was that only one instance was being used. In case of multiple instances, the settings variable could be passed to the function.  So its all clear in my mind now :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is because 'settings' is shared between all of the text imput elements that have the plugin applied to them. You need to work out some way of storing an instance of settings for each element.